# Boostrap responsitive image is deform in carousel mode

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I'm newbee in Boostrap and I try since 2 days to manage Boostrap carouseul mode. 
My images in slide are Disproportionate when I resize navigator ! I was unable to find solution. I try many solution in CSS but I naver finnd solution.

I use default CSS parameter, present in carousel mode. I try carousel mode from w3schools (image are not corrupt when we resize navigator).

**My CSS**

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="media/image1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Secucampus.com</h1>
          <p class="trans"> bla bla</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Plus d'informations</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="media/image2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Secucampus.com</h1>
          <p class="trans">bla bla</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Contactez nous</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="media/image3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="text-align:left">
          <h1>bla </h1>
          <p></p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Contenu des cours</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

The result when I resize image to Smarphone mode :
[image: Boostrap image resize to min width]

Thank for your help

Regard

Edit : Banzay :
I try to remove it and the result decrease image in hignht when I reduce the width of the navigateur.
[image]

Comment: could you provide a html head of the page?

Comment: why did you state `  height: 500px;` for `.carousel-inner > .item > img`? is it possible remove it of replace with something like % units?